# Windows XP keeps writing on disk (clock ticking)

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

From time to time, Windows XP (on laptop Dell Latitude D530) goes into strange mode - **it writes (or reads?) from disk in 1 sec intervals** without apparent reason. It is just short HDD reads/writes, but every second - it is like **clock ticking**, very well audible. The computer is idle. I have killed Firefox already (because it caused similar problem by constantly writing session data), stopped ESET antivirus. When I look to the task manager and add colums for read/written I/O bytes, no increments are observed. Yet the HDD is being accessed every second, making constant rythmic noise and flashing the LED. I have already disabled the Windows XP indexing service. Sometimes it stops, but later it comes again, without apparent reason.

Do you have any idea what could cause the problem?

Edit: the window of ProcessExplorer as recommended by @kmg90 - it doesn't show the name of the process writting, and also it doesn't show anything in the disk bar (the HDD access was every second but it has not appeared in the running bar).

[image]

*EDIT (as response to all the comments):*  This issue is not easy to reproduce. It happens unpredictably after computer has been overloaded and it usually looks like Firefox is the guilty one, but it continues even after killing it and many other apps. And there is no way to stop it, only restart the computer. So reply the advices to look if it does in safe mode - it doesn't do it even in normal mode after reboot, before something happens (some overload) and then regardless of what you do it continues to do it on and on. There is no apparent culprit, no process that would have increases in I/O stats.

**EDIT**: I tried CrystalDiskInfo from the [tools recommended by harrymc](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-health-monitoring-utility.htm). I don't understand the output very well. It shows that there are like 100 errors in "read error state" which is over the threshold of 50, but it says that "health status is GOOD". How shall we interpret this?

[image]

**EDIT**: Installed SpeedFan, another tool recommended by harrymc, and ran the short test. Shows no errors and maximum Fitness and Performance of the HDD:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the hdd is failing I would replace it.

Comment: @Ramhound - are you for real or is it irony? To the closer: what is opinion based on this problem?

Comment: Why would I joke around?  The behavior you describe is a sign the hdd is about to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I was not sure if you were joking... because I was suspecting OS, sorry.. of course I want honest possibilities. Is there any log where I can find HDD errors? I tried to look in administrative tools > event viewer but I've found nothing.

Comment: Thanks @Psycogeek, but the problem you talk about and the linked question are only about LED blinking (caused by CD-ROM), but what I experience are actual HDD operations - **I can hear the HDD very well**. The "ticking" is pretty annoying, especially on this DELL the HDD is not very quiet. PS: sorry maybe my question was not clear, updated it.

Comment: What if windows xp is not running? For example, does it happen if you're in the BIOS setup?

Comment: I disagree with @Ramhound, not because I think he's right or wrong, but because "the hard drive is failing" seems to be the quickest answer IT people give, and based on my 11 years experience, they're wrong 99% of the time. A hard drive will make ticking sounds and perform constant random access reads/writes for hundereds of reasons. Don't be too quick to replace a drive. DO HEED HIS WARNING AND BACK UP YOUR DATA.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and advices; please see my updated question for my response.

Comment: Have you tried using other OS, and letting firefox to eat your resources(try any Linux distro, like [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)), or other HDD? Just to narrow down the list of suspects.

Answer (score 3):

Initial diagnoses says add more RAM. A computer will use the hard drive as virtual RAM storage [page files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/12/14/what-is-the-page-file-for-anyway.aspx) and typically cranks away the Hard drive constantly.

The not so jumpy diagnoses, assuming you have 2+ gigs RAM, is that the OS is simply running basic diagnostic scans for viruses via windows defender, moving fragmented/unused files, garbage collecting unused resources, etc. Just because you're not doing anything does not mean your computer isn't. Typically the computer performs these tasks when the CPU reaches a certain time of day or high enough idle percentage. This makes sense since a user is obviously not using the PC if its idle is at 98%.

Comment: Well but it is pretty annoying to hear HDD sound every second. Is there some way to stop it? Note that not every Windows XP was doing that... Maybe depends on setup somehow?

Comment: Go to start menu and right click 'my computer' and select 'properties' from the menu. Make a note of how much RAM you have. Hit CTRL+ALT+DEL, select task manager, and then select the 'performance tab' Are the green bars under 'PF Usage' full? If so, your computer is using your HDD for virtual memory and you need more RAM. If not, than you either have a virus or a virus scanner running in the background. Best guess.

Comment: Not at all full; also the Physical Memory available was several hundreds MB. It is not the swap issue. This was actually regular ticking pattern - just short reads/writes, but every second.

Comment: Try pressing F8 at startup and booting into safe mode. If the hard drive continues grinding away then you know it's a system issue, otherwise it's some third-party software / drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your responses and advices; please see my updated question for my response.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use task manager to monitor I/O activity as it doesn't count EVERYTHING your computer is doing.

I would suggest using [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Microsoft SysInternals as it will make it a lot easier to pinpoint what is producing the hard drive activity.

All you need to do is run the program, hit Ctrl-I and click on the I/O tab.

It should show 3 bars for the 3 different types of I/O, including disk

Hover your mouse cursor over the disk graph to see what processes is generating the hard drive activity.

Comment: I tried ProcessExplorer but it didn't show anything - please see my updated question

Comment: Unfortunatelly this wasn't any useful. It seems to me that ProcessExplorer doesn't show anything which wasn't shown by the Task Manager. And neither of them is able to see those "HDD ticks" in the stats.

Answer (score 1):

From SysInternals there's another program named "Process Monitor" (not Process Explorer). It will produce an absolutely overwhelming amount of data, Even on a non very busy system, this can produce thousands of events per second. So filtering its output is a challenge. Luckily there are a lot of filters, and some are predefined for you. Do check those, because these predefined filters filter out many of the "normal" background chatter which you may be looking for.

Basically, what ProcMon does is capture *every* file access, registry access and network access, and log the relevant parameters, as well as the call stack.

This means that you might see that `Explorer.EXE` read `C:\temp\testfile.txt`, but that this call actually came from `Plugin.DLL` within Explorer.

Comment: Strange. When I tried it but cannot load any filter. I hover mouse over the menu `Filter > Load Filter` but no submenu pops up. And it should because there is a right arrow suggesting so.

Comment: You probably don't have any filter saved. The normal way is to open the existing list `Ctrl-L` and then add new entries or remove unwanted entries.

Comment: Tried it but this actually seems as a big challenge, which renders this unusable for me (unless someone more capable will recommend filter for me).

Answer (score 0):

Try the Windows Task Manager.

Go to the Processes tab, use the menu View / Select Columns and tick `I/O Reads` and `I/O Writes` and press OK.

Next time the problem occurs, start up Task Manager
and try to catch a process whose count changes every time you hear a tick.
If you succeed, post its name so we can comment on it.

If you can find no such process, then it is probably the disk's firmware that is the
cause of the tick, and then the disk itself is suspect.

Comment: harry, please read my question carefully: *"When I look to the task manager and add colums for read/written I/O bytes, no increments are observed"*. And regarding the disk firmware, please read the part after "EDIT". It happens only after certain load of the system.

Comment: Sorry for not seeing that, but I fear the worst in that case. Excuse the dumb question : You have of course ticked in the task manager "Show processes from all users".

Comment: Harry, no! But I am the only user using that computer. When I check it, nothing changes (no processes are added to the list).

Comment: This is impossible, because without this option only your programs are shown while system services are not shown, which are the best candidate for causing the ticks. Try using instead [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). But I'm starting to get worried about your Windows.

Comment: harry, I was already trying ProcessExplorer, see my question and comments to kmg90 answer

Comment: Do you see in Task Manager many svchost.exe processes when "Show processes from all users" is ticked? Do they disappear when unticked? (These are the system services.)

Comment: There are like 6 of them now, but now the ticking is not very strong (not every second). *Nothing* changes by ticking/unticking - the list stays the same all the time. My XP user is called "Tomas" not admin but has administrative rights.

Comment: You are right - in XP there is not that much separation between accounts. I still think that if "Show all" is ticked and nothing can be seen then the disk is doing it on its own. This doesn't automatically mean a defect, but possibly a warning sign. If the disk and motherboard support S.M.A.R.T then you should look at the health indicators.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Where can I find such thing?

Comment: There are heaps of tools : [Best Free Hard Drive Health Monitoring and Diagnostic Programs](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-disk-health-monitoring-utility.htm).

Comment: Thanks harry, I tried CrystalDiskInfo, it shows some errors but at the same time it shows "Health status: good". What a contradiction? Please see my updated question.

Comment: Reallocated sectors mean sectors gone bad and remapped to "spare" ones. Their presences is a bad sign, but the 100/50 numbers are too round, so I don't trust them. From the [specs](https://storage.toshiba.eu/cms/en/hdd/product_overview/product_detail.jsp?productid=218) your drive supports S.M.A.R.T., so I would suggest to install [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php), ensure that it correctly reads the disk info, then let it run on startup and to consult it when ticking starts.

Comment: Installed SpeedFan but the short test shows no errors. Not sure how I can take any useful info out of this. Please see my updated question.

Comment: The SpeedFan test shows that the disk was fine when tested. I would have a look again when the ticking starts at the disk's information, such as temperature. If this isn't useful, and if task manager isn't useful, in your place I would stop looking for problems but take backups every day just in case. Keep SpeedFan as it can alert you to problems, and keep on running CrystalDiskInfo weekly to see if anything changed. In other words, put your disk on probation and stay alert. You could also backup a disk image from time to time using a 3rd-party tool (not Windows Backup).

Comment: Thanks harry, but what makes you so sure it's a disk issue? AFAIK there haven't been any diagnostic supports for this so far, or were they?

Comment: I am not sure, just being cautious with unexplained ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your hard drive is about to fail. I would advise to move all of the data from your current hard drive onto an external one, purchasing a new hard drive and installing that one in place of the external one, and then copying the data from the external drive onto the new one that was just installed. Better yet- just put the external drive into your computer in place of the failing one.

You best be doing this soon as well, as a hard-drive may fail at any moment without warning if it is experiencing problems like what you are describing.

Comment: From which diagnostic output you conclude that my harddisk is going to fail? That's all still just a speculation. I need solid diagnosis to confirm this.

Comment: This is based on experience. A couple years ago the same problem happened to a laptop I was using with a similar Hard-Drive (It was a 120 GB Toshiba). At random moments the hard drive would randomly start producing a clicking noise at a very fast speed, and this would last for a good 15 to 30 minutes before it stopped again, and then occur again later. I opened it up and it turns out that the stylus was lagging behind and hitting a metal support within the casing and then bouncing back to where it should have been. This did slow down file loads quite a bit at times.

Answer (score 0):

I own a Dell Latitude D830 and the hard drive clicks in a similar fashion as you describe.

The solution (at least for me under Linux) was to turn off the drive's power management, which parks the drive's heads when idle causing the clicking.

On Linux (or cygwin) you can do that with: `hdparm -B 255 hda`

[BrightHub has instructions for Windows](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/72474.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

IF you do end up getting a new HDD, and don't want that ticking sound, perhaps a Solid State Hard Drive is what you want. No moving parts in it from what I hear.

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question. Post it as comment.